# How do I store and add links to a vector of references in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a situation in which I have an object of Class1 and a vector of objects of Class2. My goal is to have the object of Class1 contain references to certain objects in the vector of Class2. Class1 contains the members:

```
std::vector<Class2&> links;

void addLink(Class2 &obj)
{
  links.push_back(obj)
}
```

I then want to iterate through the objects of Class2 and for any objects which meet a certain condition, I want to add a link like so:

```
for (std::vector<Class2&>::iterator i = vector2.begin(); i != vector2.end(); ++i)
{
  if (condition_satisfied(*i))
  {
    obj1.addLink(*i)
  }
}
```

However, doing this gives me compile-time errors of C2528: pointer to reference is illegal. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Consider http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper

Comment: A vector of references does not make sense. What you want is a vector of pointers, I guess.

Comment: Given that the vector doesn't own the objects, you could try a vector of plain pointers.

Comment: Forgive my naiveness, but why doesn't a vector of references make sense.

Comment: @rowanphilip, a reference cannot be reassigned. It makes it problematic if the vector needs to be resized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::vector<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) requires `T` to be [CopyAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable) in C++98, [Eraseable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Erasable) in C++11,  but a plain reference is neither. In other words, references cannot be stored in `std::vector`.

You may like to use plain pointers instead. Or [`std::reference_wrapper<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper), which is a pointer in disguise.

Comment: Note that CopyAssignable was the requirement until C++11. Since then, Erasable has been sufficient (although many member functions do have stricter requirements).